# Namespaces and scope visibility issue

Tags: c++

I made a header file `sampleheader.h` with following code:

```
namespace sample_namespace
{
    int add(int n1,int n2)
    {
        return (n1 + n2);
    }
}
```

Now my main.cpp file is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "sampleheader.h"
using namespace std;

int add(int n1, int n2)
{
  return (n1 + n2);
}

int main(void)
{
    using namespace sample_namespace;
    //cout<<add(5,7);
}
```

The project is built with no warning if i leave that line commented.It is understandable because the local `add()` function is defined in the global scope and `add()` function is made visible in the scope of main(). So no name conflict happens.

However, if I remove the comments, I get the following error:

`"Ambiguous call to overloaded function"`

First of all there should be no name conflict at all as explained by me above (if I'm right). But, if at all there is a name conflict why is it that it is notified by compiler only when I call the function. Such type of error should be shown as soon as a name conflicts (if at all).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't see how this has anything to do with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"using namespace" does not hide other implementations.  What it does in this case is make it ambiguous.

You have both sample_namespace::add and ::add with the same signature.  Since you don't explicitly say which one to use, the compiler can't tell.

Declaring both functions is legal and unambiguous (which is why the compiler only complains when you use the function).

Comment: hi Tomalak Geret'kal, 
thnks 4 ur hlp.If i'm not wrng,
what u said would be similar to sayin that this code: 

#include <iostream> 
int n = 5;
int main()
{
int n = 10;
std::cout << n;
}

wouldn't work fine as it is unknown
which n to print,local n or ::n and if u 
answer by sayin that
local n hides ::n, havent i done the same thing,

I explicitly made sample_namespace::add() visible
in scope of main() so, if i use add() without any
scope name then it should take
sample_namespace::add() because it has been explicitly
made visible in local scope and ::add() should be hidden.

Comment: @sumit: Please use the "@name:" syntax so that I get notified of your comment. I found this by chance.

Comment: @sumit: No, that is not the same thing. You have a local `n` which will take precedence. In your other example, `sample_namespace::add()` is visible under the name `add()`, but it's still at _namespace_ scope.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you explained it yourself.

When you have both `int add()` and `int sample_namespace::add()` in scope, the call is ambiguous. The statement `add()` could mean either of them.

There is no conflict in the functions co-existing because one is `int add()` and the other is `int sample_namespace::add()`. This is the entire *purpose* of namespaces.

You just have to be clear when you write code that uses them. If you get rid of your `using namespace` directives and always write explicit code, then you won't run into a problem:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace sample_namespace {
   int add(int n1, int n2) {
      return (n1 + n2);
   }
}

int add(int n1, int n2) {
   return (n1 + n2);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << sample_namespace::add(5,7);
}
```

<sub>(Also, defining non-inline functions in headers is A Bad Idea™.)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it's legal to declare both functions like that is because you can call both unambiguously, by qualifying them. That's why you get an error only when you make an unqualified call. Up to that point, there is not even a theoretical problem.

Intentionally, `using namespace X;` shouldn't introduce ambiguity errors by itself. That would very much defeat the purpose of namespaces. The common `using namespace std;` introduces many names that you'd reasonbly define yourself as well.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot shadow symbols like that, only variable names (which is a warning on most compilers, i.e. a bad idea).  using directives aren't precise in any sense, which I think is the assumption that most people make.

using directives will import a symbol into the scope.  for instance, you can do things like this:

```
namespace foo {
  using namespace std;
}

foo::string val;
```

This sort of practice leads to some very annoying compiler errors to track down.  Your simple example is clear where the error is.  If you try doing it in a few hundred thousand lines of code, you will be much less pleased.

I would advise you not to acquire the habit of relying on the using directive.  If you must, just do one type at a time.

```
using std::string;
```

Basically, this keeps you honest.  And **if there is a naming conflict, grep will take 30 seconds to uncover where the problem is**.

If you just spend a couple weeks typing std:: in front of your types, you will get used to it.  I promise that the amount of time you think you are saving is greatly exaggerated.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is because of compiler-optimisation. When your string is commented - he saw, that there are some function, but you don't use it, so he discard it. And when he saw that function useful - he want to insert function call, but can't chose which one you want.

Comment: Compiler optimisations have nothing to do with it. These semantics are well-defined.

Comment: As i understand question was : why when function called - error occured, and when function don't call there's no compile-error, but overloading exists.

Comment: I know what the question was, and the answer does not involve optimisations.

Comment: hi Tomalak Geret'kal, tahnks for ur atempt but, if i'm not wrong, what u said would be similar to say that:                                                                #include <iostream>                                                           int main()